# Display hidden div and scroll to it

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am developing a single page application, in that I have three divs which I need to show hide respectively. In the middle div I have tabs where I perform swipe.

I am using Hammer.js for swiping and jquery-scrollto.js for scrolling

HTML

```
<div id="revolutionary">revolutionary</div>
<div id="middle">middle</div>
<div id="agendaa">agendaa</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var revolution = document.getElementById('revolution');
var rev = new Hammer(revolution);

rev.on("swiperight", function(event) {
    alert('swiped');
    $('#agendaa').css('display', 'block').ScrollTo();
});

//Agenda
var agenda = document.getElementById('agenda');
var agen = new Hammer(agenda);

agen.on("swipeleft", function(event) {
    //alert('swiped');
    $('#revolutionary').css('display', 'block').ScrollTo();

});
});
```

Here when I swiperight a div at the bottom will be displayed and then scroll to that div.
When I swipeleft a div in the top should display first and the scroll to that div.

What happening here is the scrolling animation is working for bottom div but not working for top div.

EDIT: scroll to bottom div also not working, the scroll action is working after the divs are displayed (second swipe)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#revolutionary').show( 'fast', function() { this.ScrollTo(); } );
```

I think what's happening is that the element doesn't actually get displayed until the event handler returns.